# c++ vector position set to 1 instead of 0

Tags: c++

I have a question about vector position. as we know know that if we were to store something into a vector. it will begin storing the first element at position 0.

so for example I have 3 things in my vector

```
vector position 0 ->itemOne  
vector position 1 ->itemTwo
vector position 2 ->itemThree.
```

is there anyway I can do to make the first element store at vector position 1 instead of position 0?

Comment: No. And why would you want to?

Comment: i you say that what you want to do is highly unrecommended, but it would be possible to achieve this by adding a dummy element at position 0 and just ignore it.

Comment: C/C++ uses 0-based indexing, because it is less prone to off-by-one errors and because of it's natural correspondence to addressing. If you do otherwise, the only thing you'll achieve is unmaintainable code.

Comment: I fear that you've accept that it is 0-position based language and really you should use it as that. Please don't write code which behaves _unexpected_ concerning the indexes, because it is hard to maintain and will cause problems whenever you want to call functions written by others.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a dummy first element. Please don't though, everyone using C++ expects vectors to be 0-based.

If that isn't what you had in mind, then no, there's no way. Simply because the element in the first position is accessed using the index `0`. So `position 1` is *your* representation of `vec[0]`. Just  a name.

Or switch to Pascal.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a wrapper around vector and overwrite the `[]` operator. However I believe this is highly inadvisable   as any sane developer will be mislead by your code.

Comment: This would not be necessarily misleading if intention and naming is made clear. It could actually reduce risk of off-by-one bugs if vector wrapper is used for storing already indexed data. In that case it would be better to implement [] or `at(n)` like method with more accurate name, another thing is that wrapper like this should not look like an std::vector.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can insert a dummy into position 0. And the real value one later on.
Surely You want to iterate AND access using "humanly indexers".
This will mostly fail for the last entry.
This language is zero index based.

Comment: I think it is a bad idea, because it is not a stable solution - e.g. just think what happens after sorting the elements.

Comment: Surely this idea is not recommended. But its that, what op asked for.
It is possible to put first element on index 1,

Answer (score 1):

Vector is just an array, so this is 0-indexed. Of course you can store a dummy data on position 0, but I recommend you to subtract 1 from the position you desire.
Or if you can find some library (wrapper) that uses 1-indexed vector like:
 https://www.rosettacommons.org/manuals/archive/rosetta3.4_user_guide/d3/dd5/classutility_1_1vector1.html
Or you can simply create the desired class that can access the desired element by the index which starts by 1.